# How to dereference a pointer passed by reference in c++?

Tags: c++, reference, pointers, dereference

I'm doing (something like) this:

```
void insert(Node*& node, string val, Node* parent)
{
   if (node == NULL)
     instantiateNode(node, val, parent);
   else
     insert(node->child, val, node);
}
```

The thing is, that `instantiateNode(..., parent)` seems to modify the original `*&node` passed into the function when setting the `*parent`. `instantiateNode()` is *supposed* to alter the `node`, but if it alters the `parent` than you have a node that is set to its parent, which doesn't make sense, and also doesn't work. At all.

The reason I'm bothering with pointer references at all is because it eliminates special cases and significantly reduces the amount of error checking I have to do. Since I'm doing it to reduce line count and trivial algorithm-ish duplication, I can get around this by approximately doubling the code line count. But I'd rather not, and I feel like there **should** be a way to dereference a pointer reference to get a new pointer that points to the same object. And, really, I thought that pass of `*&node` through `*parent` should have done it, but apparently gcc is optimizing it out.

Comment: Can you post your full code and what it is that you are trying to achieve? This looks like a fairly straightforward insertion, why are you even dealing with pointer references?

Comment: Your question sounds unclear. Why not post instantiateNode? That it should modify the node pointer (and the whole thing should also be able to modify parent) seems rather expectable to me.

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what change of behaviour of that code snippet you are looking for. I would assume that the whole point of passing `node` as a reference would be that it can be modified from inside the function. Also the function name `instantiateNode` seems to suggest that it would create a new node, probably by modifying it's parameter. And about copying a pointer, do you mean `Node *copy = node;`?

Comment: "apparently gcc is optimizing that out" -> no it's not.  Don't blame the compiler/optimizer.  It's almost never wrong, and GCC is wrong even less often than most.  Your code is doing what you told it to do, which may or may not be what you intended.

Comment: I should have added to my previous comment that the optimizer is not allowed to change how your program behaves.  Only in the weirdest of circumstances (undefined behavior, optimizer bugs, and a few things in the spec like assignment/copy constructor elision) will it do so.

Comment: @Uri: sorry, I can't post it, I would almost certainly get in trouble and/or anger someone.

Comment: @sth: I just edited, hopefully it's more clear now. `instantiateNode` is basically a wrapper around a constructor call and default assignments from the `insert()` environment. And yes, that's what I mean by copy. I've tried doing that, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @rmeador: The optimizer is "not allowed" to, but it can change things if it thinks that it won't. The reason I thought it was doing something like ignoring the actual types that I was using is because I had an error earlier where it was passing references around instead of I think copying. It was a couple weeks ago, I don't remember exactly what it was, but I definitely had some weird reference errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there should be a way to dereference a pointer reference to get a new pointer that points to the same object.

Well, how about this?

```
Node* n = node;
```

Now you've got a non-reference pointer that points to the same object as node, exactly what you asked for.

I am 95% sure the problem you are facing has nothing to do with references, and everything to do with faulty logic in instantiateNode or your use of it.  That's why it would be useful if you gave us more information about what the code is supposed to do, or even posted the code to instantiateNode.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I think I let myself get caught up in details, but I tried that, early on, and gdb suggests that it is still pointing to the wrong thing. But even doing `Node* n = &(*node);` doesn't fix it, so either I'm just out of luck or, more likely, I'm doing something stupid. It's a small function, though, and I've written tons very similar to it, and I've re-written it I don't even know how many times, and etc, and so I still am unsure about what is going on. If I figure it out, I'll be back.

Answer (score 3):

node is a reference to a pointer, which means that if the function sets node, the value passed in is changed. That's how references work.

If you don't want node to change in the calling function, don't make it a reference.

Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: No, you're right: I want node to change. But then I think that when I pass it to `insert()` as `parent` (which is not a reference) it should be copied and `parent` should be a new pointer that points to the same place as `node` did in the previous function.

Comment: But you're not passing `parent` into `insert()`.

Comment: `node` becomes the `parent`, because `insert()` operates on the child of the node. The signature: `insert(node, item, parent)`. The call: `insert(node->child, item, node)`

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that you are calling `insert` recursively. Yes, the second time insert is called, the `parent` variable in that frame should be the same as the `node` variable in the caller's frame. You can change the thing that `parent` points to (i.e. the contents of the Node structure), but you can't change `parent` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `node` needs to be passed by reference.  A simple pointer should do the job.  This is because you don't ever need to change it directly.  Why are you passing it to `instantiateNode()`?  It will always be NULL, so what good does it do?  If `instantiateNode()` also has its first argument passed as a reference, why?  You are passing in the parent, so `instantiateNode()` can just access the thing `node` should represent via `parent->child`.  Even if for some reason `instantiateNode()` does take it's param by reference and it's required to do so, I believe the function will still work if you drop the reference from `insert()`'s first argument.  Whatever `instantiateNode()` does with that value will simply be lost when the function returns.  I'm sorry that's so confusing, but I can't think of a better way to word it.

There's another interpretation of your problem... maybe your call to `insert()` should read:

```
insert(node, val, node->child);
```

Comment: The code just appears to build a list, it just appends to the lasts nodes child, i.e. where child==0. Supposing thats what it should do it looks fine to me.

Comment: What happens is that I pass it in, and if it's NULL, I set it to a new child. So I'm actually affecting the pointer itself. It could be done with minor acrobatics by doing a whole lot of condition checking, though. The only reason I'm doing it like this is because it's a 3-5 tree, and I don't want to have to check 3-5 things on every loop.